# Mind Mapping tool exporting data to Rally

Tags: csv, xml-parsing, rally, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from a Mind mapping tool such that it can be imported into Rally. Trying to create a mindmap of backlog which can be easily exported to a format compatible to rally ("csv"). I tried using different tools that export data to "csv" format which is Rally-compatible, however ran into some issues and hence decided to get the data into xml format and further convert just the required fields from the xml data to csv which can then be imported to rally.

What I have now is a process that can convert data to xml, I then further use a tool to get it to csv but the hierarchical structure of mindmapping is not maintained when I convert it to csv. So basically, now when I import "csv" data to rally, it doesn't keep parent relationships ( as seen in Mindmapper tool ) in backlogs.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Rally Excel plugin](http://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide) that allows import to Rally from an Excel spreadsheet?
It does not have a direct support for importing parent/child relationship between stories, but if a story designated to be a parent already exists in Rally or imported first, then you may import another batch of stories with Parent field specified, and that will link the newly imported story or stories to the parent. See this [video](http://help.rallydev.com/import-export-excel-addin).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I am looking for is a total Integration with a Mind mapping tool such that information can be exported from such a tool in a format such that it can be imported into Rally. The Rally Excel Plugin needs the excel spreadsheet to be in a specific format ( I can write some code for it ) but my concern is to maintain parent-child relationships between stories which will be sketched out by the mind mapping tool, so the parent won't be pre-existing in Rally.

Comment: There is no out of box integration with Mind mapping tool. If the limitation of Excel plugin vis-a-vis parent/child relationship makes it less suitable for your purpose, you have to may consider writing your own integration as long as th Mind mapping tool has an API. On a Rally side, you may use any one of the toolkits (.Net, Java or Ruby) listed here here: https://help.rallydev.com/for-developers